# How do you enumerate over an array of blocks?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
self.myArray = @[ [^{ NSLog(@"a"); } copy],
                  [^{ NSLog(@"b"); } copy]];
```

... Later ....

```
[self.myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // This syntax is wrong, but I hope you get my intention
    void (^) (void) block = obj;  
    block();
}];
```

How do you cast out the block when enumerating over it?  (Bonus if you can do it without a typedef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From art-divin's comment this is probably a better way of doing it.

```
NSOperation* aOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{ NSLog(@"a");}];
NSOperation* bOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{ NSLog(@"b");}];

NSOperationQueue* opQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[opQueue setSuspended:YES];
[opQueue addOperation:aOp];
[opQueue addOperation:bOp];
```

... Later

```
[opQueue setSuspended:NO];
```

Answer (score 10):

```
[self.myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    void (^block)() = obj;  
    block();
}];
```

Or directly in the argument list:

```
[self.myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(void (^block)(), NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    block();
}];
```

Comment: + 1 for altering the argument list - I didn't know you could do this!

Comment: you can use NSOperationQueue and -[NSOperation operationWithBlock:] instead of directly saving blocks in array. If there is a class for this exact purpose (with possibility to start/stop execution) designed by Apple developers, then you should definitely use one.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
void (^block )(void) = obj;
```